# how to use -wall and -werror and compile c file in linux

Tags: embedded-linux

I was using soekris box for my embedded linux assignment where i had to compile my c file using -war and -werror . can any body help me how can i use this two minimal flag while compiling?

Comment: Try showing what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to your Makefile as CFLAGS.

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
```

Comment: /opt/fontys/soekris/bin/i586-linux-gcc -o mygame -lusb xpatext.c 

where actually i have to put -wall and -werror cflags while compiling  like this

Comment: Try this: `/opt/fontys/soekris/bin/i586-linux-gcc -o mygame -lusb -Wall -Werror xpatext.c`

Answer (score 2):

Just open the terminal and enter something like this:
`gcc -x c -c -Wall -Werror ./path/to/our/fency/c/file.c` ?

I added a few more flags:

```
`-x c` - tells the compiler that it's a C code.
`-c` - tells the compiler just to compile, no linking.
```

And ones You asked for:

```
`-Wall` - turns all warning reporting.
`-Werror` - tells to make all warnings into errors.
```

You can read some more about gcc flags by checking `gcc --help` or in [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html).